# Use/View Lightning Component on Classic/Visualforce page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I created this page in order for my lightning component to be viewed also in classic.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="BDE" ></div>
    <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:BDE_App", function(){
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:BDE_Wizard", {}, "BDE", function(component){});   
    }); 

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

this is the BDE_App:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <div class="mainContainer">
        <c:BDE_Wizard />
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

My lightning component is BDE_Wizard. I've already created the tab but for some reason nothing displays.What might be missing?

Comment: Are you confused about the JavaScript, or how to make a Tab?

Comment: hi, I've updated my question after trying... hope it makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to define the dependency:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:BDE_Wizard" />
</aura:application>
```

A Lightning Dependency App should not attempt to show any components directly.